# Export to doc gives runtime exception 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in DevExpress.Printing.v19.1.Core.dll

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, export, devexpress

```
try
{
    // Using DevExpress.XtraPrinting.Link to export to pdf
    compositeLink.ExportToDocx(fileName);
    MessageBox.Show("Word file exported successfully at " + saveFile.FileName, 
                    "Exported Successfully", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\n\n" + e.StackTrace);
}
```

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in DevExpress.Printing.v19.1.Core.dll Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) 

at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
    at DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintingSystemBase.CreateDocxExportProvider(Stream stream, DocxExportOptions options)
    at DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintingSystemBase.ExportToDocx(Stream stream, DocxExportOptions options)
    at DevExpress.XtraPrinting.Native.FileExportHelper.Do(String filePath, Action1`1 action)
    at DevExpress.XtraPrinting.LinkBase.ExecuteActivity(PrintingSystemActivity activity, Action0 callback)
```

Comment: Isnt there any e.InnerException instance to tell more?

Comment: No, there wasn't but after adding e.InnerException.Message showed me the real reason and now the issue is solved. Thanks @MichalHainc